# i need help on finding the minimum number of

Tags: javascript, jquery, calc

im trying to figure out how to display the minimum number of each box needed to ship an order. i've done most of the work but still cant seem to finish the program. here's what i have so far in the js:

```
var calculate_boxes = function() {

    var dvds = parseFloat($("dvds").value);

    //Be sure the value entered is a positive number.

    var cave =  dvds / 24;
    dvds = dvds % 24;    

    var bakers =  dvds / 13;
    dvds = dvds % 13;   

    var dimes =  dvds / 10;
    dvds = dvds % 10;

    var quads =  dvds / 10;
    dvds = dvds % 10;

    var twins = dvds / 4;
    dvds = dvds % 4;

    var minis = dvds / 1;
    dvds = dvds % 1;    

        cave   = parseInt($("cave").value);
    bakers  = parseInt($("bakers").value);
    dimes   = parseInt($("dimes").value);
    quads   = parseInt($("quads").value);
    twins   = parseInt($("twins").value);
    minis   = parseInt($("minis").value);

}
```

Comment: What is the problem / question you are facing? What is not working?

Comment: What are you doing with that last block of jQuery objects? `$("cave")` is trying to select all `<cave>` elements, which doesn't seem right. Likewise for the others. Also, jQuery objects don't have a `value` property. There is a `val()` method though. As Pekka asked, what is not working specifically? Give us some more context.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting up variables like `var cave =  dvds / 24;`, but then later in the function you overwrite those variables with values like `cave = parseInt($("cave").value);` - I'm guessing what you are trying to do is covert the decimal value currently stored in the `cave` variable to an integer, but by using the jQuery code `$("cave").value` what your code actually does is try to select an element with the tag name "cave", i.e., `<cave>` and get its value, and then pass that value to `parseInt`.

In JavaScript you can convert a decimal to an integer using one of several of the [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) methods - which one to use depends on whether you want to round up, down, or to the nearest integer.

For your current purpose you always want to round down, so use [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor). There is no need to do it as a separate operation at the end of your function, just do it immediately:

```
var cave = Math.floor(dvds / 24);
dvds %= 24; // note that dvds %= 24 is equivalent to dvds = dvds % 24

var bakers = Math.floor(dvds / 13);
dvds %= 13;

// etc
```

Also, presumably your "quads" should divide by 4 and your "twins" should divide by 2.

Also, I'm not sure why you start out with `parseFloat()` at the beginning of your function - it doesn't make sense to be able to order a fractional number of DVDs. In addition to the currently missing positive-numbers-only validation you need to check that an integer was input.

Also, your final calculation for "minis" is doing a pointless division by 1: at that stage you know that `minis = dvds` with no dvds leftover so you don't need the pointless modulo operation on the next line either.

If you apply the above changes and get rid of the `parseInt()` stuff you should be much closer to your goal: try it out and experiment a bit and get back to us if it still doesn't work.